# Error: AotPlugin was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class

Tags: angularjs, node.js

### problem

```
ng serve
```

> Module build failed: Error: AotPlugin was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.

Full error report log

```
  ERROR in ./src/main.ts
  Module build failed: Error: AotPlugin was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
  This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.
  at Object.ngcLoader 
 (D:\testingapp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:358:19)
  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

---

```
npm ls @ngtools/webpack
```

---

```
testingapp@0.0.0 D:\testingapp
 +-- @angular/cli@1.2.6
 | `-- @ngtools/webpack@1.5.5
`-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
 `-- @ngtools/webpack@1.5.1
```

---

```
npm cache verify
```

still problem still exist.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 6):

This problem occured for me after running `ng eject` and trying to run my karma tests.

Even though I do not think that this is an optimal solution I worked around the problem by:

1. Removing `@ngtools/webpack`

   `$ npm remove --save @ngtools/webpack`
2. Requiring the `@ngtools/webpack` that is a child dependency of `@angular/cli` in my webpack.config.js

   ```
   // webpack.config.js
      //
    // Other require statements
    const { AotPlugin } = 
   require('./node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack');
   /* 
   * Change the loader 
   /* 

     module.exports = {
       // ...

        "module": {
       "rules": {
        // ...
         {
         "test": /\.ts$/,
         /* REMOVE: "loader": "@ngtools/webpack", */
         "loader": 
           "./node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack"
             }
        }
        // ...
        }
        }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had very a similar problem with a different version @angular/cli@1.4.9 and @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4

```
├─┬ @angular/cli@1.4.9
│ └── @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4
└── @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4
```

The code below can be found along with the instructions at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli 

rm -rf node_modules dist
npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and its fixed now.

First check versions of all your dependencies using `ng -v` and check the same for other working app and you'll surely get some version differences, so try to downgrade/upgrade to working ones.

In my case, I had node 8 installed which was causing the same issue. By simply downgrading via nvm solved my problem.

[how to install nvm link one](http://dev.topheman.com/install-nvm-with-homebrew-to-use-multiple-versions-of-node-and-iojs-easily/)

[how to install nvm link two](http://michael-kuehnel.de/node.js/2015/09/08/using-vm-to-switch-node-versions.html)

you can follow either of links to install nvm

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Just updated angular-cli and did an npm update and everything is fine.

I'm starting to suspect that updating angular-cli is the ongoing equivalent of "have you tried turning it on and off again?" ;)

Comment: I suspect that this error only occurs when the versions of the immediate  `@ngtools/webpack` dependency and the @ngtools/webpack (child dependency of `@angular/cli`) diverge.